# Intel XDK App development Camera not working Andorid

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I have written a simple code to open the camera in Phone and take picture. The code works fine on the emulator but on testing the device, its not working. Camera plugin has been included. Here is my code. Let me know if i am doing something wrong:

```
<script>
  function capture()
    {
        intel.xdk.camera.takePicture(50, true, "png");
    }

    function importLib()
    {
        intel.xdk.camera.importPicture();
    }

    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.camera.picture.add", function(event)
                              {
        alert("Successfully");
    });
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.camera.picture.busy", function()
                              {
        alert("resource busy");
    });

    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.camera.picture.cancel", function()
                              {
        alert("operation cancelled");
    });
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Does the provided "example camera app" work when built and deployed to your device? Can you add your build settings to your post?

Comment: @DanielBrown thank you. found my mistake. But i did not understand if i was not including intel xdk plugin in the code how come the emulator was showing the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I did a stupid mistake, included the cordova plugin for camera that is why the demo camera app was working perfectly.
My code is using the camera api provided by Intel XDK, did not add that plugin in the settings. Its working now :)